# Eigen library got "comma initilizer", why make column-major the default?

Tags: c++, eigen

According to the documentation for the Eigen (C++) library, the default matrix is column-major. So effectively, a small 3x3 matrix will be something like

```
1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9
```

Then it got **comma initializer**, the front end appears to be row-major like, but the backend is still column-major

```
Example: (from eigen doc)
Matrix3f m;
m << 1, 2, 3,
     4, 5, 6,
     7, 8, 9;

std::cout << m;

output: 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Yes, I realise that **RowMajor** is all you need to create a row-major matrix. I am wondering, since they have **Comma initializer**, why do they make column-major the default?

Comment: I asked myself a similar question. Which is: Why make the comma initialiser row-major when that's not your default?

Answer (score 1):

One reason, maybe not major, would be when interfacing with raw data buffers.  The matrix buffers sent to via OpenGL to shader programs are column major, and the similarity allows you to send an Eigen matrix to the shader with only a call to .data()